# How does CVE-2014-9390 affect me?

Tags: vulnerability

On 18th December, a vulnerability in git and mecurial was announced.

- What are the details of the vulnerability?
- Does it affect me?
- What should I do?

Answer (score 36):

> What are the details of the vulnerability?

Git stores repository metadata in a `.git` sub-directory. This includes [git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) that allow custom scripts to be run at various points in the git workflow. Git normally does not allow any files in this sub-directory to be committed.

However, sub-directories like `.Git` on *can* be committed into the repository. This vulnerability arises because operating systems with case-insensitive filesystems (such as Windows or OS X), will treat the two sub-directories (`.Git` and `.git`) as equivalent and will overwrite `.git` with the contents of `.Git`. This results in an attacker being able to execute arbitrary code by tricking users using operating systems with case-insensitive filesystems into cloning a maliciously crafted repository.

> Does it affect me?

The vulnerability only works on users using case-insensitive filesystems. This include most Windows and OS X users.

Pulling repositories from GitHub is safe because GitHub now [blocks](https://github.com/blog/1938-vulnerability-announced-update-your-git-clients) repositories from containing the malicious exploit.

> What should I do?

As with all new vulnerabilities, *upgrade* the affected software. This means upgrading to versions v1.8.5.6, v1.9.5, v2.0.5, v2.1.4, and v2.2.1 of git depending on which maintenance branch you are using.

Comment: Another detail: It's not *only* computers with case-insensitive filesystems that are vulnerable. Windows and OS X can both be set to treat files in a case-sensitive way, but even then filenames like `git~1` (on Windows) and `.g\u200cit` (on OS X) will be treated the same as `.git`, leaving both of those operating systems vulnerable to this exploit. ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/2pq04n/critical_git_security_vulnerability_announced/cmzhu5o))

Comment: Also, servers can benefit from the fix, too; see https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2014/12/securing-your-git-server/